# Image in the middle between header and footer - CSS

Tags: html, css, image, center

I want to built a simple landing page with a header,footer and an image - exactly between the header and the footer (horizontally/vertically centered).

The space between the header/footer and the image should be the same and should depend from the height of the browser-window.

The image has a fixed width (900px) and a fixed hight (600px).

Aw: it is a sticky footer

I have tried something like this:

```
{display:block; padding:0 40px; width:900px; margin:0 auto; vertical-align:middle;}
```

my html:

```
     <div class="fbg">
<div class="fbg_resize">
    <img src="images/image.png" width="900" alt=""  />
</div>
    <!--<div class="clr"></div>-->
```

to get it horizontally centered:

```
.fbg_resize { margin:0 auto; padding:0 40px; width:900px;}
```

here is the code that matters:

http://jsfiddle.net/SFWBL/

Comment: Is the footer pinned to the bottom of the page? (sticky footer?)

Comment: You need to show us any code you have attempted so far and not just ask for someone to make it for you

Comment: Please show the complete code including HTML and CSS in your question, preferably in a http://jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BYTam/7/) for the basic premise, it should be enough to get you started.

HTML

```
<div id='header'></div>
<div id='image'></div>
<div id='footer'></div>
```

CSS

```
html, body{
    text-align:center;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#header, #footer{
    height:50px;    
    width:100%;
}
#image{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    margin:-25px auto 0 -25px;
    background:grey;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}
#header{
    background:blue;
}
#footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `img`, you can try `background-image` for the `div`

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.fbg {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/900/600);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SFWBL/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Relative (percentage) positions are the way to get your elements to recognize the size of the browser window. Since they work on the edges (top, left), you have to use a negative margin to move the item back up half the height of your item. Since you know the fixed height of your image is 600px, you need -300px. You want to give your image:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%:
margin-top: -300px;
```